# Findbugs and FindSecBugs in Sonar

Tags: sonarqube, findbugs, static-code-analysis, sonarqube-web

I wanted to have an extensive static analysis of our code so chose FindBugs as the Sonar profile. However I also want to have a good security analysis too for which I can see there's a profile called Findbugs security Audit in SonarQube. Is there a way where I can use both of them to analyse our code without having to create a custom profile?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There is not a way you can apply two different rule profiles to the same project at the same time. You can choose one or the other but to have the rules from both you'll either need to edit one of them or create a 3rd profile.

Note that this is not hard too do.

1. create a new profile (it's empty at this point)
2. go to the **Rules** page
3. Use the Quality Profile facet to search for the rules active in the first source profile - click on the profile, and 'active'
4. Use **Bulk Change** to activate them in your new profile
5. repeat steps 3 & 4 for each source profile.

There's no need to worry about overlaps - rules active in multiple source profiles will be activated once and only once in your target profile.